# Determine the size and brightness of 'shorttitle' in apa6 style

Tags: fonts, header-footer, apa6

In a paper I am currently writing, I am using the apa6 style. I want to include a short title in each page, but the default font in apa6 is too large, so it looks like each page starts with a new title:

[image: too large short title]

Here is the line that generates the short title:

> \shorttitle{A Sample Short Title}

**I want to change the size of the short title, and maybe make it less bright**. I have tried to search for a solution in the web, as well as change some parts of the 'apa6.sty' file, but without success.

EDIT: I have managed to change the **size** of the title, by using:

> \font\myfont=cmr12 at 10pt
>
> \shorttitle{{\myfont A Sample Short Title}}

The question regarding the brightness still remains.

Comment: Can you please add a small example document which shows what you're doing. And I have no idea what you mean by "brightness"? Do you mean that the title appears in all upper case letters?

Comment: @AlanMunn By brightness I mean the lucidity level of the text. I want it to be less bold.

Comment: But the text is normal weight to begin with (other than being all caps). So there is no boldness to be reduced.

Comment: I've added a comment about making the text of the header grey.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `apa6` documentclass uses `fancyhdr` to format the page headers, so you can redefine the style of them there.

```
\documentclass[man]{apa6}
\usepackage{kantlipsum} % for dummy text
\shorttitle{My short title}
\makeatletter
\fancypagestyle{titlepage}{%
    \lhead{\small\rheadname: {\@shorttitle}}%
    \rhead{\small\thepage}%
}
\fancypagestyle{otherpage}{%
    \lhead{\small{\@shorttitle}}%
    \rhead{\small\thepage}}%
\makeatother
\pagestyle{otherpage}
\begin{document}
\kant
\end{document}
```

You should use proper LaTeX commands for changing the font size, `\small`, `\tiny`, `\footnotesize` etc. The command `\font\myfont=cmr12 at 10pt` is the plain TeX way of defining a font, and should not be used.

Reducing the "brightness".  If you really want to make normal text less black, then you should load the `xcolor` package and add `\color{black!50}` (or some suitable number < 100) to make the text of the header grey.

```
\usepackage{xcolor}
...
\lhead{\small\color{black!50}\rheadname: {\@shorttitle}}%
...
```

[image: output of code]